# How to stringify sqlite query with questionmarks to see a query which will be executed in a text form?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have a program. The program makes a lot of sqlite queries. And it does them in an optimized ? way i.e.

```
UPDATE controls SET value = ? WHERE rowid = ?
```

What I'm looking for: if there is some whey to evaluate/stringify a query from sqlite3 back for debugging purposes.
I.e. I'd want to see that really the query above which has been executed is:

```
UPDATE controls SET value = 108 WHERE rowid = 42
```

Obviously I can write this myself, but I think my desire is "common" i.e. I'd expect something similar should be there already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite offers a function that provides exactly that. One can find more information on this in the documentation:

> char *sqlite3_expanded_sql(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt);
>
> The sqlite3_expanded_sql(P) interface returns a pointer to a UTF-8 string containing the SQL text of prepared statement P with bound parameters expanded.
>
> ...
>
> The string returned by sqlite3_expanded_sql(P), on the other hand, is obtained from sqlite3_malloc() and must be free by the application by passing it to sqlite3_free().

see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/expanded_sql.html

And indeed, if you put the call of sqlite3_expanded_sql between binding the parameter and executing the update so:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, 108);
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, 42);

char *expanded = sqlite3_expanded_sql(stmt);
printf("expanded: %s\n", expanded);
sqlite3_free(expanded);

rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

Then the output on the debug console is:

```
expanded: UPDATE controls SET value = 108 WHERE rowid = 42
```